# NodeJS socket.io don't work on android Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have the following problem: 
I created a simple chat app with the this system as core (https://github.com/kishorekumaru/ChatSystem__Sample). 
Now I started this app on a debain server and on the desktop it works perfectly but when I opened the page on my Adnroid device and started Google Chrome brwoser, the page shows up but when I want to enter something it doesn't do anything. 
There is also no data displayed. 
I think that the Android browser can't connect to the databas. 
But why?

My server.js file is the same like in the Github rep. (see above).
I only added new styles and a button to send the messages so far.

**EDIT 1**
I tried debugging it with Google Remote Debugging (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging#remote-debugging-on-android-with-chrome-devtools) then it works as designed, when I unplug the cable it crashes again....

Best regards 
Tobias

Comment: What debugging info have you collected on Android?  What errors?  This should be solved by diagnosing what is actually happening on Android, not by just looking at the code.

Comment: I tried debugging it with Google Remote Debugging (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging#remote-debugging-on-android-with-chrome-devtools) then it works as designed, when I unplug the cable it crashes again....